# Run program in system terminal

Tags: visual-studio, ide, visual-studio-code

How do I set Visual Studio Code to run programs in the system terminal like Codeblocks or Dev-C++ do instead of the integrated one. I find it to be more clear. I tried changing different settings but without success.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you are using windows? In this case try the following configuration in the tasks.json:

```
    {
        "label": "buildrun",
        "type": "shell",
        "command": "start",
        "args": [
            "cmd.exe",
            "@cmd",
            "/K \"",
            "echo command1",
            "&&",
            "echo command2",
            "\""
        ],
        "problemMatcher": []
    }
```

I simply started cmd.exe from the integrated terminal and gave it the necessary commands. 
Of course you can add or remove these as you wish.